# JSF f:param - parameter not accessible

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I passed a parameter "parent" as following.

```
<h:commandLink rendered="some contidion" >
    <td>
        <a href="home.xhtml">
                <img  src="icon.png" width="140" height="140" alt="alternate" />
        </a>
    </td>                       
    <f:param name="parent" value="ABC" />
</h:commandLink>
```

But on home.xhtml, I can't read it as:

```
#{param.parent}
```

What's the mistake I m doing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `h:commandLink` in a wrong way. You don't need to embed a `a:href`. Use the `action` attribute.

Or better if you don't want to call an action method use `h:link`:

```
<h:link outcome="home" >
   <img ...>
   <f:param name="parent" value="ABC" />
</h:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your home.xhtml likes here

```
   <h:outputText value="Value, {0}">
        <f:param value="#{yourBean.name}"/>
   </h:outputText>
```

You can replace h:outputText into h:outputFormat or something likes this.